# bind select from api using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, drop-down-menu, ng-options

I'm trying to populate a Select getting data from a webapi using ng-options.

Basically, my webapi returns the following JSON:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"X",
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "name":"Y",
         "id":2
      }
   ]
}
```

And I Need to generate options in a select displaying the name property, but with the id as value.

The problem is that I can't display my options using ng-options. Here's what I'm trying:

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <title>angular</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='DemoCtrl'>
    <select ng-model="selectedTestAccount" ng-options="option.name for option in testAccounts">
        <option value="">Select Account</option>
    </select>
    <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', []).controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
            $scope.testAccounts = [];

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/values',
                data: {}
            }).success(function (result) {
                console.log(result);

                $scope.testAccounts = JSON.parse(result.items);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you

```js
angular.module("app", []);
        angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

          $scope.testAccounts = [];

            var youJson = [
                { "items": [{ "name": "X", "id": "your value for X" }, { "name": "Y", "id": "your value for Y" }] },
                { "items": [{ "name": "A", "id": "your value for A" }, { "name": "B", "id": "your value for B" }] }
            ];

          angular.forEach(youJson, function(items) {
            angular.forEach(items.items, function(item) {
              $scope.testAccounts.push(item);
            });
          });

          console.log($scope.testAccounts);
        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in testAccounts"></select>
  {{mySelect}}
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost, it didn't display the id as options's value

Comment: I think you are wrong, it return exactly your id value!! just change your select option you will see the id value